# How to change the url of a webview ofter users installed it? Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm building an iOS App with Xcode in Swift. 
I have a webview in my app. But I don't want it to direct one specific url. I need to change the url occasionally, even after the users installed it.
I don't know if it's possible and I haven't got a solution after searching around for a while.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: This didn't help? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html

Comment: I successfully used those instructions to build a webview. But I couldn't find a way to change the url from time to time....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a few ways of varying degrees of difficulty and flexibility:

1. If you knowing advance a number of suitable sites, you can maintain an array of URLs and load different entries based on whatever criteria you desire.
2. You can update the array  or a single URL through app updates.
3. You can have the preloaded URL be a domain you own which is set to be redirected to any URL you chose.  This is easy and cheap.
4. You can create a web service.  Not for the lighthearted if you have never done it.

Comment: Thanks! 1,I'm not sure which url I'll load when I finish building the app; 2, It'll be too frustrating for me to update the app because I'll do that pretty often; 3, Yes I have a domain in my name. This sounds like the best idea!! But how to redirect it? technically? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad you can make progress!